# Can you name multiplicative bivariate convex functions?

Tags: functions, economics

can you please provide me as many bivariate functions $f(x,y)$ which are increasing both in $x$ and $y$ and are convex (result into concave isoquants)? I need them not to be additive between $x$ and $y$, e.g. $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ does not work

Comment: What do you mean by not additive between $x$ and $y$

Comment: I mean that the function should be multiplicative between $x$ and $y$, I.e. $x$ and $y$ should not compare in the function as a sum

Comment: What about taking $$f : (x, y) \to \exp(xy) $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess this would not work either, since the isoquant would read $y = \frac{\log(k)}{x}$ which is convex, while I need the isoquant to be concave

Comment: Ah yes, keep me inform if you find such a function ;)

Comment: I have one if you need : $f : (x,y) \to -xy $